# Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":2,"values":5}

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, mint

```
struct 721Data {
        uint tokenId;
        string tokenURI;
        LibPart.Part[] creators;
        LibPart.Part[] royalties;
        bytes[] signatures;
    }
struct Part {
        address payable account;
        uint96 value;
    }
```

and this is how I am passing the values to it and it gives an error `[1,"ASDFG",[["0xD1709F2eD4e29aCC1a37D5aDa1983d782a27BfA8",10]],[["0xD1709F2eD4e29aCC1a37D5aDa1983d782a27BfA8",10]],0x0]`

Comment: What's the function signature? and what is the code used to encode the parameters?

Comment: Can you add more information that you try to archive?